# Graphics card monitoring utility

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, computer-building

Is there a software from XFX to monitor the graphics card temps/fan speeds/etc, like MSI's afterburner utility?  Can I use another software/utility to monitor a XFX GT 240 card?

I'm on Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[MSI Afterburner](http://event.msi.com/vga/afterburner/download.htm) can be used for other card manufactures beyond MSI.  It is one of the best tools out there.

You can also use [GPU-Z](http://www.techpowerup.com/gpuz/).  It is a very simple tool that can monitor all the vitals of your video card.

Comment: can i control the fan of an XFX card with the MSI utility?

Comment: @zm15  Yes, the only reason it might not work is if your card happen to have a non-smart fan.  Try out afterburner and let us know how it goes. http://event.msi.com/vga/afterburner/download.htm

Answer (score 3):

Check out [GPU-Z](http://www.techpowerup.com/gpuz/).